# Solving a linear system with matrices

Tags: matlab, math, linear-algebra

Can any one tell me please if there is a matlab function to solve the following equation to find *X*:

*A*X*A=B*

Where *A*, *B* and *X* are all squared matrice *(n by n)*.

Additional information:

- A X and B are all symmetric.
- B and X are definite positive,
- det(A)=0.

Comment: Eigendecomposition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix

Comment: Can you please be more precise. X is not diagonal, it's also a matrix.

Comment: Are you looking to do an LU decomposition?

Comment: `X = inv(A)*B*inv(A)` by the definition of the matrix equation... you're going to have difficulty finding a solution to that if `A` has no inverse because `det(A) = 0`. By have difficulty, I mean there will either be no solutions or infinitely many solutions (related, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249919/for-deta-0-how-do-we-know-if-a-has-no-solution-or-infinitely-many-solutions))

Comment: You didn't put any restrictions on the shape of `X`, only that it's definite positive which is what the middle matrix in eigendecomposition would give you.  However, because you have `det(A) = 0`, you will not get a unique answer.

Comment: @Wolfie: The matrix is not inversible because det(A)=0.
@ ProgrammingEnthusiast: No In fact, I'am trying to find the matrix (it's not a vector) given A and B.

Comment: @rayryeng, I do agree with you, X is real symmetric so it can be decomposed using spectral theorem. I'm looking for any solution X that is semi-definite positive

Comment: @yasare The answer to your question is no.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a mathematics problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: @Wolfie Thank you for your answer, I didn't see all the comment the first time.

Comment: @Wolfie, I think we can post mathematics questions either. Don't think you so?

Comment: @rayryeng: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate.

Comment: If you want to post a mathematics question, post it on https://math.stackexchange.com/, this is specifically a programming branch of the StackExchange network. See the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking here.

Comment: @Wolfie Ok thank you, I didn't know about this before. Thank you once again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution, because the determinant of the left hand side is 0 (because det(A) = 0) whereas the determinant of the right hand side is positive (because B is positive definite).

Answer (score -1):

In general there won't be a solution. In particular there will only be a solution if B is singular, for

```
det( AXA ) = det(A)*det(X)*det(A) = 0
```

One way to proceed would be to diagonalise A, ie find orthogonal U and diagonal D so that

```
A = U*D*U'
```

If we substitute this into your equation, we get (*)

```
D*X~*D = B~
```

where

```
 X~ = U'*X*U 
 B~ = U'*B*U
```

For simplicity suppose that D is of the form

```
D = ( d 0 )
    ( 0 0 )
```

where d is non-singular. If X~ and B~ are partitioned conformably as

```
X~ = (X11 X12)
     (X21 X22)
B~ = (B11 B12)
     (B21 B22)
```

then from (*) we get

```
( d*X11*d 0 ) = ( B11 B12 )
( 0       0 )   ( B21 B22 )
```

Thus there is only a solution if B12, B21 and B22 are all zero, and then

```
X = U*( X11 X12 ) * U'
      ( X21 X22 )
```

where

```
  X11 = inv(d)*B11*inv(d)
```

and X12 X21 and X22 are arbitrary